# Is there ObjectTracking in RealityKit or SceneKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I tried out object detection in SceneKit but the object is only detected in the beginning once virtual objects are placed the object is no longer detected or tracked. I remember reading that object detection is not a continuous process but can not find that resource anymore. Please share resources that might be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

ARKit 4 introduces two new types that conform to `ARTrackable` (`ARAppClipCodeAnchor`, and `ARGeoAnchor`), but no changes in `ARObjectAnchor`.

Also, while I was researching a little more about the subject, I found that [Vision framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) provides [object tracking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_multiple_objects_or_rectangles_in_video). This might be useful in some situations.

---

First, I will try to clarify some concepts.

[SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit) is a rendering framework, so its work is to render virtual objects on the screen.

[RealityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit) is also a rendering framework. This one was created by Apple to help developers in creating better AR experiences.

That said, rendering frameworks don't actually track anything in the real environment, like physical objects or images. The responsible for understanding the real world is [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit). ARKit can detect real objects, images, etc., in the physical world.

Going back to your question, in order to be tracked, the physical object should have a correspondent anchor (`ARAnchor`) in your app that conforms to [ARTrackable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable). As you can see in the documentation, the conforming types of `ARTrackable` are `ARBodyAnchor`, `ARFaceAnchor`, and `ARImageAnchor`. Object anchors are of the type [ARObjectAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arobjectanchor), and, as you can see in the docs, this class doesn't conform to `ARTrackable`, meaning that physical objects can't be tracked on ARKit 3.0. ARKit only **detects** the object, but doesn't track it. In the future, object tracking might be supported.

Comment: Correct. The resolution on object detection is very low, so ARKit currently couldn't track objects very well if it tried. ARKit 3.5 is in beta, and there are no changes to object detection there either.

Comment: @Bobjt I saw in your profile that you write ARKit docs. I don't know if this is the best place, but I would suggest updating the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) to change "Object Tracking" to "Object Detection". Should I file a bug for that?

Comment: Yep. No need to file a bug for that; it's getting fixed with the ARKit 3.5 documentation batch that'll go live probably around Wed. 3/25.

Comment: Anyone know if there is any change to this with LiDAR iPad/new iPhone? Or if there are any 3rd party ways to track 3D objects?

Comment: @JonathanPlackett I updated my answer but the tl;dr is that you can try Vision framework for object tracking. For now, ARObjectAnchor still doesn't conform to ARTrackable.